Max number of edges in $p$-uniform hypergraph on $n$ vertices with $|E_1\cap E_2|\le 1$ for any two distinct edges $E_1, E_2$
This is an equivalent formulation (with different notations!) of the problem from a recent AoPS thread (which is unsolved for one and half month):

Given a $p$-uniform hypergraph $H=(V, \mathcal E)$ with $|V|=n$ and $|E_1\cap E_2|\le 1$ for any distinct $E_1, E_2\in \mathcal E$ what is the maximum number of edges $|\mathcal E|$?

My idea was to bound the number $d(E)$ of edges intersecting with a given edge $E$ (and distinct from $E$), and then use some double-counting to find the relationship between $|V|, |\mathcal E|$ and $p$. Particularly, I used the trivial bound $d(E)\le |\mathcal E|-1$ and the formulas
$$\sum_{v\in V}\deg v = p|\mathcal E| \qquad \text{and} \qquad
2\sum_{v\in V}\binom{\deg v}{2} = \sum_{E\in \mathcal E}d(E). \tag{*}$$
The first one follows by double-counting the pairs $(v, E)$ with $v\in E$ and the second one by double-counting the triples $(v, E_1, E_2)$ with $E_1\cap E_2 = \{v\}$. Then I used Jensen for $f(x)=\binom x 2$ to estimate from below the LHS of the second identity in $(*)$, and used my bound of $d(E)$ to estimate the RHS in $(*)$ from above. This resulted in
$$2|V|\binom{\frac{1}{|V|}\sum_{v\in V}\deg v}{2} \le |\mathcal E|(|\mathcal E|-1)
\qquad \Longrightarrow\qquad
|\mathcal E|\le \frac{n(p-1)}{p^2 - n}$$
where I assumed $p^2> n$ for this to make sense. But this is, as far as I understand, too far from the real maximum.
Anyway, this setup of this problem seems to be fundamental enough to be already investigated. So I tried searching on the web but could not find useful articles.
My question is, are there any known bounds for $|\mathcal E|$ or possibly a complete solution to this problem?

You should have $d(E)\leq n-1$ (think of a sunflower, or a star if $p=2$). It should change the remaining calculations (and give an even worse bound).

Thanks @pasthec for your observation. Very interesting, tough to be honest I am not sure I fully understand why necessarily $d(E)\le n-1$. I assume it may follow from this result or at least some modification of the proof for it.
Anyway I carried out the calculations with this new estimation and actually does not look too bad. For some relationships between $n$ and $p$ the new bound seems better.

Ok what I wrote is completely false (there is a counter-example for $p=3$ already), I entirely misread the statement the first time, sorry for this. Luckily the previous nonsense made me think of an actual bound, and not very far from the wrong one : $d(E)\leq p\lfloor(n-p)/(p-1)\rfloor$. This comes from the fact that for each of the $p$ points of $E$, the other edges intersecting $E$ at this particular point form a $p-1$-uniform matching on the remaining $n-p$ points. It's tight for $p=3$. And as I originally misread the statement, this actually gives you a better (and not worse) bound!

For $p\ge 4$, the bound on $d(E)$ might be improvable, but it also becomes asymptotically closer to $d(E)\le n-p$. I have no idea if doing Jensen on this gives an optimal upper bound, but I have to go to bed now. Also I agree that this definitely looks like something that would have been already studied by someone.

After looking it up this was indeed studied and the bound is close to what we get from summing my inequality, see thm 3.2 of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10114-023-0597-0
Now I should really get sleep.

Now I remember what I meant in my 1st comment, that $d(v)\leq \lfloor(n-1)/(p-1)\rfloor$ (which is $n-1$ for $p=2$...). Summing up gives exactly thm 3.2 (and is basically the same proof).
I'm still curious if Jensen gives something better, or if this bound is reached for some construction. I did not dive in the bibliography too much either so it might have been studied more precisely.

Very nice and very interesting, @pasthec! Your bound of $d(E)$ is indeed the one I was looking for (and I had sort of similar judgement which was flawed unfortunately, it can be found in the AoPS thread). Applying this estimation and keeping the remaining logic the same I get $|\mathcal E|\le \dfrac{n(n-1)}{p(p-1)}$ which at least does not need $p^2>n$! I could not access the article you pointed but have requested the text from the authors.

I just realized that using $\deg v \le \lfloor (n-1) / (p-1)\rfloor$ we get the same bound (as with using the bound of $d(E)$ and Jensen)!
$|\mathcal E| = \dfrac{1}{p}\sum_{v\in V}\deg v \le \dfrac{n}{p} \left\lfloor \dfrac{n-1}{p-1}\right\rfloor.$

This MO post has more information.
